# Finding indices in Python lists efficiently (in comparison to MATLAB)

Tags: python, matlab, list, numpy

I have got difficulties to find an efficient solution to find indices in Python lists. All the solutions I have tested so far are slower than the 'find' function in MATLAB. I have only just started to use Python (therefore, I am not very experienced).

In MATLAB I would use the following:

```
a = linspace(0, 1000, 1000); % monotonically increasing vector
b = 1000 * rand(1, 100); % 100 points I want to find in a
for i = 1 : numel(b)
    indices(i) = find(b(i) <= a, 1); % find the first index where b(i) <= a
end
```

If I use MATLAB's arrayfun() I can speed this process up a little bit. 
In Python I tried several possibilities. I used

```
for i in xrange(0, len(b)):
   tmp = numpy.where(b[i] <= a)
   indices.append(tmp[0][0])
```

which takes a lot of time, especially if a is quite big. 
If b is sorted than I can use

```
for i in xrange(0, len(b)):
    if(b[curr_idx] <= a[i]):
        indices.append(i)
        curr_idx += 1
    if(curr_idx >= len(b)):
        return indices
        break
```

This is much quicker than the numpy.where() solution because I only have to search through the list a once, but this is still slower than the MATLAB solution.

Could anyone suggest a better / more efficient solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `linspace(0, 1000, 1000)` have 1000 elements changing from 0 to 1000 including both, giving a lot of floats, is that really what you want? On the other hand, the `xrange` works with integers.

Comment: `numpy.where(b <= a)`? No need to do that in a loop.

Comment: @M4rtini, `b <= a` doesn't work for incompatible sizes (`b` has 100 and `a` has 1000 elements). He wants a process for each b[i], not a `numpy.nonzero` elementwise.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have to search through vectors (arrays, lists) which are consisting of floats. I basically want to find indices for a list of floats occurring in a (longer) list of floats if that makes sense. I am using `xrange` in this case only to go through every item of b,  therefore `integers` are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `numpy.searchsorted`:

```
>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>> b = np.array([1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 2, 9])
% sorting b "into" a
>> np.searchsorted(a, b, side='right')-1
array([1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 2, 9])
```

You might have to apply a little special treatment for values in b, that are outside the range of a - such as the 9 in the above example.
Despite that, this should be faster than any loop-based method.

As an aside:
Similarly, `histc` in MATLAB will be much faster than the loop.

**EDIT:**

If you want the get the index where `b` is closest to `a`, you should be able to use the same code, simply with a modified a:

```
>> a_mod = 0.5*(a[:-1] + a[1:]) % take the centers between the elements in a
>> np.searchsorted(a_mod, np.array([0.9, 2.1, 4.2, 2.9, 1.1]), side='right')
array([1, 2, 4, 3, 1])
```

Note that you can drop the `-1` since `a_mod` has one element less than `a`.

Comment: This is in fact the fastest solution I have tested so far. Quicker than all other possibilities in Python, but slower still a bit slower than find in matlab. If my array b would look like the following: `b = np.array([0.9, 2.1, 4.2, 2.9, 1.1])`, is there a way to find the indices where `b[i]`is closest to one item in `a`? The output for a case like this using your example above for `a` should be `[1, 2, 4, 3, 1]`. Is this possible?

Comment: In fact I cant imagine that this is slower than the `numel(b)` loops in MATLAB...sure? °°

Comment: `a = array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7])`
;
`b = array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.4,  0.3,  0.1,  0. ,  0.2,  0.9])`
;
`np.searchsorted(a, b, side='right') - 1` resulted in `array([1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 2, 7])`, but 0.9 > 0.7. What happens when `max(b) > max(a)`?

Comment: As I mentioned: "You might have to apply a little special treatment for values in b, that are outside the range of a". Besides, this case isn't covered in the OP's MATLAB "reference" code. You can easily remove all `b`'s smaller than `min(a)` or greater than `max(a)` in a step before the sorted-search (or afterwards).

Comment: `np.searchsorted` is about 2x faster in the current development branch of numpy than it is in 1.8, so if you can compile your own numpy, or wait a couple of weeks until numpy 1.9 is released, Python may be in the lead again.

Comment: Pypy with iterators is still solving this about 3x faster than CPython + Numpy, even when using `np.searchsorted` (see my solution). I'm with Numpy 1.8.1 installed here (on both Python 2 and 3).

Comment: I tested both this and the original MATLAB code; this one blows OP's code out of the water with a 44x improvement (for OP's original array sizes).

Comment: @sebastian: Thank you very much. That works exactly the way I was looking for. I have not tested the solution with pypy and the generators yet.

Answer (score 0):

With numpy only for number generation (not for vectorization):

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000)
b = 1000 * np.random.rand(100)
indices = [next(i for i, ai in enumerate(a) if bi <= ai) for bi in b]
```

This works if `a.max()` >= `b.max()` as in the example, otherwise will raise a `StopIteration`, and it's still slow (although this one doesn't make every possible comparison like in `b(i) <= a`).

If you need the indices as an array instead of a list, use `np.array(indices)` after that. If you need some optimization, you can sort `b` and keep only one `enumerate(a)`, peeking instead of taking the last element.

You can also try without numpy on pypy:

```py
def igen(a, b):
    iterb = iter(b)
    bi = next(iterb)
    for i, ai in enumerate(a):
        while bi <= ai:
            yield i
            bi = next(iterb)
    i += 1 # Last bi are bigger than all ai
    yield i
    for unused in iterb:
        yield i

from random import random
a = (i * 1000. / 999. for i in xrange(43032500))
b = sorted(random() * 1000 for unused in xrange(3848))
indices = list(igen(a, b))
```

This one is based on generators using that idea, and b should be sorted. This will return `len(a)` when `bi > ai` for all `ai`.

For testing, I'm using:

```py
setup = """
from random import random

def igen(a, b):
    iterb = iter(b)
    bi = next(iterb)
    for i, ai in enumerate(a):
        while bi <= ai:
            yield i
            bi = next(iterb)
    i += 1 # Last bi are bigger than all ai
    yield i
    for unused in iterb:
        yield i
"""

program = """
a = (i * 1000. / 999. for i in xrange(43032500))
b = sorted(random() * 1000 for unused in xrange(3848))
indices = list(igen(a, b))
"""

# Python 2 and 3 compatibility
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    program = program.replace("xrange", "range")

# Time it! =)
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(program, setup, number=5000))
```

That means I'm running 5 thousand times that algorithm in each environment. The resulting time is the SUM of all trials (`program`) duration (not the mean value):

- On CPython 3.4.0 result was `11.491293527011294` (seconds)
- On CPython 2.7.6 result was `9.39319992065` (seconds)
- On Pypy 2.2.1 result was `3.31203603745` (seconds)

More specific version messages:

- Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
- Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
- Python 2.7.3 (2.2.1+dfsg-1, Nov 28 2013, 05:13:10) [PyPy 2.2.1 with GCC 4.8.2] on linux2

Now the same with the "two ifs" version adapted (code below) had the results:

- On CPython 3.4.0 result was `13.03860338096274` (seconds)
- On CPython 2.7.6 result was `10.7371659279` (seconds)
- On Pypy 2.2.1 result was `2.88891601562` (seconds)

Pypy found a way to optimize your version but still have one difference, I've tested this one calculating "a" just once, while my version calculated "a" 5000 times. The code I've run was:

```py
setup = """
from random import random
a = [i * 1000. / 999. for i in xrange(43032500)]
"""

program = """
b = sorted(random() * 1000 for unused in xrange(3848))
curr_idx = 0
indices = []
for i in xrange(len(a)): # Why not for i, ai in enumerate(a)?
    if b[curr_idx] <= a[i]:
        indices.append(i)
        curr_idx += 1
    if curr_idx >= len(b):
        break
"""

# Python 2 and 3 compatibility
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    setup = setup.replace("xrange", "range")
    program = program.replace("xrange", "range")

# Time it! =)
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(program, setup, number=5000))
```

Another version would just put the `a` assignment to the `program` instead of keeping it on the `setup`, doing so the Pypy time goes to `2102.06863689` (yeah, more than 35 minutes). Storing things on a huge list is really slow. Changing the program beginning to:

```py
a = (i * 1000. / 999. for i in xrange(43032500)) # A generator expression
[...]
for i, ai in enumerate(a):
    if b[curr_idx] <= ai:
    [...]
```

Brings us back to `3.11599397659` seconds with Pypy. On this version, `a` is created 5000 times, but never stored on a list. On the other hand, the `igen` version "hardcoded" outside of the function worked on `3.17516112328` seconds, in which `setup` just imported `random` and `program` was:

```py
a = (i * 1000. / 999. for i in xrange(43032500))
b = sorted(random() * 1000 for unused in xrange(3848))
indices = []
iterb = iter(b)
try:
    bi = next(iterb)
    for i, ai in enumerate(a):
        while bi <= ai:
            indices.append(i)
            bi = next(iterb)
except StopIteration:
    pass
else:
    i += 1 # Last bi are bigger than all ai
    indices.append(i)
    for unused in iterb:
        indices.append(i)
```

Anyhow, let `A = len(a)` and `B = len(b)`, so these are `O[A + B.log(B)]` algorithms (including @sebastian solution with np.searchsorted). On the other hand, calculating `bi <= ai` for all pairs `(bi, ai)` is `O[b * a]`, the Matlab solution should be asymptotically slower unless it does some internal optimization to avoid full comparison making each statement completely lazy (but I don't have Matlab to verify =/). As a need for a comparison, I did this on GNU Octave:

```py
start = time;
a = linspace(0, 1000, 43032500);
b = 1000 * rand(1, 3848);
for i = 1 : numel(b)
    indices(i) = find(b(i) <= a, 1);
end
stop = time;

stop - start
```

That's one time the process Python did 5000 times, using the original code from this question, and it happened in `203.16` seconds (more than 3 minutes).

> Oh, but you're cheating! Put that "start = time;" after the assignment to "a"!

Ok, no one said that, but I've just tried such change. As every `b(i) <= a` is a vector with size 43032500, it doesn't change much: `202.83` seconds.

> And Numpy?!

Numpy also have to store the data. Mostly, it doesn't work with generators (hstack and vstack are exceptions). But we can't be sure which is fasterwithout empirical evidence. Let's run this with Numpy 1.8.1:

```py
setup = """
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(0., 1000., 43032500) # Don't count this time
"""

program = """
b = 1000 * np.random.rand(3848)
indices = np.searchsorted(a, b, side='right') - 1 # From @sebastian solution
indices[b > a[-1]] = len(a) # Big value correction (my improvement)
"""

# Time it! =)
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(program, setup, number=5000))
```

- On CPython 2.7, `9.81494688988` seconds
- On CPython 3.4, `9.831143222982064` seconds

And that's it. =)

Comment: The dimensions of the arrays do not match. You also are not taking advantage of numpy broadcasting.

Comment: Yes, the dimensions don't match, but who said they should match?

Comment: Hummm, maybe I did not understand the question precisely then.

Comment: @H.D. Thank you. This solution does what I want, but I just tested it with `len(a) = 43032500` and `len(b) = 3848` and the solution I posted with the if conditions and increasing current index is much faster. Both solutions still much slower than the MATLAB find function.

Comment: The first solution was still slow, but it should already be faster than the MATLAB one that makes several unnecessary comparisons. Now there's another solution, and this one should be at least as fast as the one with the if conditions.