# Calculating event / stimulus triggered averages efficiently in Python

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, average, performance

I would like to calculate event / stimulus triggered averages computationally efficient. 
Assuming I have got a `signal`, e.g.

```
signal = [random.random() for i in xrange(0, 1000)]
```

with `n_signal` datapoints

```
n_signal = len(signal)
```

I know that this signal is sampled with a rate of

```
Fs = 25000 # Hz
```

In this case I know that the total time of the signal

```
T_sec = n_signal / float(Fs)
```

At specific times, certain events occur, e.g.

```
t_events = [0.01, 0.017, 0.018, 0.022, 0.034, 0.0345, 0.03456]
```

Now I would like to find the signal from a certain time before these events, e.g.

```
t_bef = 0.001
```

until a certain time after these events, e.g.

```
t_aft = 0.002
```

And once I have got all of these chunks of the signal, I would like to average these. 
In the past I would have created the time vector of the signal

```
t_signal = numpy.linspace(0, T_sec, n_signal)
```

and looked for all of the indices for `t_events` in `t_signal` e.g. using `numpy.serachsorted` 
([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628503/finding-indices-in-python-lists-efficiently-in-comparison-to-matlab))

Since I know the sampling rate of the signal, these can be done much quicker, like

```
indices = [int(i * Fs) for i in t_events]
```

This saves me the memory for `t_signal` and I do not have to go through the whole signal to find my indices.

Next, I would determine how many data samples `t_bef` and `t_aft` are corresponding to

```
nsamples_t_bef = int(t_bef * Fs)
nsamples_t_aft = int(t_aft * Fs)
```

and I would save the signal chunks in a `list`

```
signal_chunks = list()
for i in xrange(0, len(t_events)):
    signal_chunks.append(signal[indices[i] - nsamples_t_bef : indices[i] + nsamples_t_aft])
```

And finally I am averaging these

```
event_triggered_average = numpy.mean(signal_chunks, axis = 0)
```

If I am interested in the time vector, I am calculating it with

```
t_event_triggered_average = numpy.linspace(-t_signal[nsamples_t_bef], t_signal[nsamples_t_aft], nsamples_t_bef + nsamples_t_aft)
```

Now my questions: Is there a computational more efficient way to do this? If I have got a signal with many data points and many events, this computation can take a while. Is a `list` the best data structure to save these chunks in? Do you know how to get the chunks of data quicker? Maybe using buffer? 
Thanks in advance for your comments and advice.

**Minimum working example**

```
import numpy
import random

random.seed(0)
signal = [random.random() for i in xrange(0, 1000)]

# sampling rate
Fs = 25000 # Hz

# total time of the signal
n_signal = len(signal) 
T_sec = n_signal / float(Fs)  

# time of events of interest
t_events = [0.01, 0.017, 0.018, 0.022, 0.034, 0.0345, 0.03456]

# and their corresponding indices
indices = [int(i * Fs) for i in t_events]

# define the time window of interest around each event
t_bef = 0.001
t_aft = 0.002

# and the corresponding index offset
nsamples_t_bef = int(t_bef * Fs)
nsamples_t_aft = int(t_aft * Fs)

# vector of signal times
t_signal = numpy.linspace(0, T_sec, n_signal)

signal_chunks = list()
for i in xrange(0, len(t_events)):
    signal_chunks.append(signal[indices[i] - nsamples_t_bef : indices[i] + nsamples_t_aft])

# average signal value across chunks
event_triggered_average = numpy.mean(signal_chunks, axis = 0)

# not sure what's going on here
t_event_triggered_average = numpy.linspace(-t_signal[nsamples_t_bef],
                                            t_signal[nsamples_t_aft],
                                            nsamples_t_bef + nsamples_t_aft)
```

Comment: I've edited your question so that you have a minimum working example of your code. This should hopefully help people who are looking at the question. Feel free to edit the code/comments if I've misinterpreted anything.

Comment: @Mr E: Thanks, that's was a good idea. Next time I'll post something I'll remind myself to use a minimal working example.

Answer (score 3):

Since your signal is defined on a regular grid, you could do some arithmetic to find indices for all the samples that you require. Then you can construct the array with chunks using a single indexing operation.

```
import numpy as np

# Making some test data
n_signal = 1000
signal = np.random.rand(n_signal)
Fs = 25000 # Hz
t_events = np.array([0.01, 0.017, 0.018, 0.022, 0.034, 0.0345, 0.03456])

# Preferences
t_bef = 0.001
t_aft = 0.002

# The number of samples in a chunk
nsamples = int((t_bef+t_aft) * Fs)

# Create a vector from 0 up to nsamples
sample_idx = np.arange(nsamples)

# Calculate the index of the first sample for each chunk
# Require integers, because it will be used for indexing
start_idx = ((t_events - t_bef) * Fs).astype(int)

# Use broadcasting to create an array with indices
# Each row contains consecutive indices for each chunk
idx = start_idx[:, None] + sample_idx[None, :]

# Get all the chunks using fancy indexing
signal_chunks = signal[idx]

# Calculate the average like you did earlier
event_triggered_average = signal_chunks.mean(axis=0)
```

Note, the line with `.astype(int)` does not round to nearest integer, but rounds towards zero.

Comment: Well explained. With events happening at arbitrary times there is nothing more one can do than fancy indexing, which should definitely bring a significant speed up wrt looping.

Comment: @moarningsun: Thank you for your code using indexing. I have just tested it and found that it is about 7 times faster on my machine than my minimal working example above.

Comment: @xaneon: Oh only 7 times, that's a little disappointing to be honest. And unfortunately I don't have any idea of another Numpy method to do this fast...

Comment: You can speed things up a tiny bit by replacing `signal[idx]` with `np.take(signal, idx)`.